# Polars in rust -- how to use group_by with custom function

Tags: rust

Say i have a custom function

```
fn my_function(df: DataFrame) -> DataFrame{
// something bespoke here
}
```

I am unsure how to apply it to grouped objects (using polars in python I would do `group_by('grouping_col').map_groups(lambda x: my_function(x))`  but not sure how to make it work in rust.

Comment: There was no need to delete your own answer. It's always good to get multiple perspectives on a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's good that you figured out one solution to your problem, the lazy API provides a far more elegant solution.

```rust
use polars::{lazy::prelude::*, prelude::*};

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let df = DataFrame::new(vec![
        Series::new("x1", [1., 3., 10., 20.].as_ref()),
        Series::new("x2", [1., 1., 1., 1.].as_ref()),
        Series::new("g", [1, 1, 2, 2].as_ref()),
    ])?
    .lazy();

    let g = df.select([
        col("x1"),
        // this is where the magic happens
        (col("x1").mean() - col("x2")).over([col("g")]).alias("x2"),
        col("g"),
    ]);
    println!("{:?}", g.collect()?);

    Ok(())
}
```

```
┌──────┬──────┬─────┐
│ x1   ┆ x2   ┆ g   │
│ ---  ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ f64  ┆ f64  ┆ i32 │
╞══════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 1.0  ┆ 1.0  ┆ 1   │
│ 3.0  ┆ 1.0  ┆ 1   │
│ 10.0 ┆ 14.0 ┆ 2   │
│ 20.0 ┆ 14.0 ┆ 2   │
└──────┴──────┴─────┘
```

It even maintained the order! In general, where it can get the job done, Polars’s lazy API will make for far simpler and more performant solutions than the eager API.

(By the way: if you're just going to unwrap everything, there's no point in using `Result`. `Result` is for when you are ok with errors bubbling up through your program. `unwrap` will abort your program if there's an error.)